# Invalid regular expression - Invalid property name in character class

Tags: regex, typescript, fastify

I am using a fastify server, containing a typescript file that calls a function, which make sure people won't send unwanted characters. Here is the function :

```
const SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP = /[^\p{Latin}\p{Zs}\p{M}\p{Nd}\-\'\s]/gu;
function secure(text:string) {
  return text.replace(SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP, "").trim();
}
```

But when I try to launch my server, I got an error message :
*"Invalid regular expression - Invalid property name in character class".*

It used to work just fine with my previous regex :

```
const SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP = /[^0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð\-\s\']/g;
function secure(text:string) {
  return text.replace(SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP, "").trim();
}
```

But I have been told it wasn't optimized enough. I have also been told it's better to use split/join than regex/replace in matter of performances, but I don't know if I can use it in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```js
const SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP = /[^\p{Script=Latin}\p{Zs}\p{M}\p{Nd}'\s-]/gu;
// or
const SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP = /[^\p{sc=Latin}\p{Zs}\p{M}\p{Nd}'\s-]/gu;
```

You need to prefix scripts with `sc=` or `Script=` in Unicode category classes, so `\p{Latin}` should be specified as `\p{Script=Latin}`. See the [ECMAScript reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-runtime-semantics-unicodematchproperty-p).

Also, when you use the `u` flag, you cannot escape non-special chars, so do not escape `'` and better move the `-` char to the end of the character class.

You can use split&join, too:

```js
const SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP = /[^\p{Script=Latin}\p{Zs}\p{M}\p{Nd}'\s-]/u;
console.log("Ącki-Łał русский!!!中国".split(SAFE_STRING_REPLACE_REGEXP).join(""))
```

Note you don't need the `g` modifier with `split`, it is the default behavior.

Comment: Here's that same link, but in the editor's draft (living) spec multipage edition: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-runtime-semantics-unicodematchproperty-p Loads rather more quickly. :-D

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work just fine !
Just to know, does a split/join structure can be used to do the same thing ?