# SyntaxError Invalid regular expression Vite / Vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, node-modules, vite

I'm stack into this error for my new Vuejs project when I run the npm run dev command.

How to solve this issue. I think its internal bug from Vite in the node_module.

I am using macOS Ventura 13.3.1.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your .env file?

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155109/invalid-regular-expression-invalid-property-name-in-character-class (just would need `gc=`)

Comment: @MaximeBaker it's just new Vue project without .env file.

Comment: @tevemadar Do you mean `sc=` ?

Comment: I explicitly wrote `gc=`, because I think that's the one. In the linked question `{Latin}` is ["script"](https://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script), but here `{L}` stands for `{Letter}` (and `{N}` for `{Number}`), which is ["general category"](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on a custom Linux-based distribution. I could fix it by installing [ICU](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/icu.html)

You can check if your node has ICU available by running `npm version`.